# How to deal with revision process in Latex (collaboration with non latex users)?

Tags: word-to-latex

How do people deal with the revision process of a document when the co-worker(s) does not use latex? I used to work with Microsoft Word and the changes tracking tool but now I started using Latex to write my thesis.

I suggested my advisor use the existent tools in Acrobat Reader for Windows, which allow highlighting, crossing out text and placing comments. However, she wants to be able to cut and paste text, and to leave comments in a similar way to how she did in Word. What is the best way to make this transition? Is there any alternative to edit pdf files directly?

Comment: It would be the best for your sanity if you don't use LaTeX in this situation. You will only get disappointed. Write the final version in LaTeX and be done with it.

Comment: You could test latex2rtf http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/manpage.html and see if your document will convert ok.  This is old software and more and more LaTeX documents will not convert correctly or even at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try importing the pdf to word and sending her that. Word's pdf importing is pretty good these days. If you warn her that minor typographical issues are an artifact of that process, that might offer a solution?

It also means there is no danger she will be distracted by the code (or foul it up), and she does not need to learn a new system or means of working (as some busy academics are understandably reticent to do).